# sqlx structscan join query

Tags: go, sqlx

I'm new to go and sqlx and I would want to know if its posible to strutscan a master -> detail join clause in one query. A patient has many episodes so I want to query all patients and embed an Episode array in each Patient struct

Something like this:

```
type Episode struct {
        EpisodeID int    `db:"episode_id"`
        PatientID int    `db:"patient_id"`
        Status    string `db:"status"`
    }

    type Patient struct {
        PatientID    int            `db:"patient_id"`
        FirstName    string         `db:"first_name"`
        MiddleName   sql.NullString `db:"middle_name"`
        LastName     string         `db:"last_name"`
        Episodes     []Episode
    }

    query := `SELECT 
    mr_patients.patient_id, 
    mr_patients.first_name, 
    mr_patients.middle_name, 
    mr_patients.last_name, 
    mr_episode_statuses.status, 
    mr_episodes.episode_id, 
    mr_episodes.created_at 
    FROM mr_patients 
    INNER JOIN mr_episodes ON mr_patients.patient_id = mr_episodes.patient_id 
    INNER JOIN mr_episode_statuses ON mr_episodes.status_id = mr_episode_statuses.status_id
    ORDER BY mr_patients.patient_id, mr_episodes.episode_id`

    rows, err := db.Queryx(query)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var patients []Patient

    for rows.Next() {
        var p Patient
        err = rows.StructScan(&p)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        } else {
            patients = append(patients, p)
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look to: https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx_test.go#L470

Comment: Thanks @molivier, I've tryed that, but as #mpm says it only works with one to one relationships. It doesn't populate episodes array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going to work since database/sql or sqlx aren't object relational mappers and don't know how to "populate" your type `[]Episodes`. sqlx can assign single struct fields within a parent struct with the "structName.fieldName" syntax but that's it. It can't take all your rows, know what is what and assign all `Episodes` to the correct `Patient`. You need an ORM for that.